# File in src but not default package? Java

Tags: java, eclipse

This may be very abstractly written, as I'm not sure of a good other way. In Java, I wrote something that creates a file and saves it in that folder. I then have another class/object that takes those files and uses those files to do some calculations. Why do I get thrown a **FileNotFoundException** when those files are saved in the default package of the src but not when they are saved outside the default package? I am working in the Eclipse IDE and was curious as to why this occurred?

EDIT:
I tried to create a file File temp = new File("src/random.txt") and this is where I was running into my problem and getting the errors thrown. It worked later when I omitted 'src' when creating the new file

Comment: You src folder does not exist when you deploy your application.  Is is there for your development

Comment: A "resource" inside your application context does not act like a "File" on the disk.  When developing you "can" reference "source" location, but when packaged, the "source" location won't exist (and won't be accessible), you should never reference your "source" location from within your code

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not sure I entirely follow this. When you say I shouldn't reference my source location, do you mean I should never specify a specific path and just let the File class handle the path? Appreciate the response as well, just trying to understand what's going on here

Comment: I'm saying, you should never have a "file" path which includes "src" (or what ever the source location might be).  You can use `Class#getResource` and/or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to references resources within you application context, but these paths would start from the root of your "source" location (but not include it).  For example, if you had images in `src/images/happy.png`, you would use `/images/happy.png` to reference it - but remember, it's NOT a file, it's a resource, so you need to use the right tools to access it

Comment: Relative paths are resolved relative to the working directory. By default, this is the project directory in Eclipse. The working directory can be changed in the launch configuration in the tab _Arguments_. On the command line the working directory is the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can guess from your description above, you are not providing path for the files, just use file names? That's why your application is looking for the files where it runs.

Comment: I tried to create a file File temp = new File("src/random.txt") and this is where I was running into my problem and getting the errors thrown. It worked later when I omitted 'src' when creating the new file. I was more curious as to why the first one threw an error because your reasoning is what I originally thought.

Comment: your code is not running in src folder. by default, it runs where your classes exists. i mean your output folder for compilation. for example : /bin. when you don't provide a path, file is created and read from where you run the code.

Answer (score 0):

provide full path e.g.

```
String csvFile = "D:\\Documents\\ex\\myFile.csv";
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(csvFile);
```

make sure you have correct file extension.